# How do I show an image on hover when an image is hovered?

Tags: image, hover, anchor

This is the code I have:

```
<a class="image_show" href="#"></a>

.image_show:
    background-image: url("/images/img.png");
    display:block;
}

. image_show:hover {
    background-image: url("/images/img2.png");
    display:block;
}
```

The above solution doesn't display the image unless there is text in there.  How can I show my image without text in the anchor tag?

Comment: Well, what are you displaying? There should be an element to hover over in order to show the image, which is why this won't work with an empty a tag

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
.image_show {
   display: block;
   width: 123; // width of your image
   height: 123; // height of your image
}
```

You could also use inline-block. This more closely resembles how a normal image would fit in a page.

Comment: Thanks! I had to use position:absolute to get it to show but that messes up other thigns in the code.